# How to parameterize java method to iterate on elements in a table?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with products' names which locators differs only by index. I would like to use one method to iterate on all of the elements, because the number of elements can be changed up to 10 and I need to go through them all.

```
    @FindBy(xpath="(//*[@class=\"product-name\"])[2]")
protected WebElement productName1;
    @FindBy(xpath="(//*[@class=\"product-name\"])[3]")
protected WebElement productName2;
    @FindBy(xpath="(//*[@class=\"product-name\"])[4]")
protected WebElement productName3;
```

A method that I want to parametrize is:

```
    public String checkProductsInCart() {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(productName1));
        String productName1String = productName1.getText();
        return productName1String; }
```

How should I do that? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML please?

Comment: @DebanjanB what do you mean by relevant HTML ?

Comment: HTML of the _table with products_ you are referring with a bit of `outerHTML`

Comment: I think you must separate this task in two methods. First will get all desired elements, and return connection with this element. Then in checkProductsInCart(), you must add two parameters, first will be the collection of founded elements, second will expected condition. Then you can start to iterate over the collection, and make the assertion part, or etc.

Comment: @Debanjan is suggesting provide some HTML where this table is located, so we could provide more exact answer.

Comment: @DebanjanB I added HTML.

Comment: @Anna Having an accepted Answer I strongly believe your query have been resolved. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. Stackoverflow volunteers will be happy to help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obtain all of the product name elements in a single list:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@class=\"product-name\"]")
protected List<WebElement> productNameElements;
```

Then, in your test method, you can iterate over the elements (you could use for loop with an int index if you prefer):

```
List<String> productsInCart = new ArrayList<>();
for (WebElement element : productNameElements) {
    productsInCart.add(nameOfProductInCart(element));
}
```

You can alter your check method to take a `WebElement` as a parameter:

```
public String nameOfProductInCart(WebElement element) {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    return element.getText();
}
```

Alternatively, if this doesn't work (e.g. because the product list takes time to populate), you could use the `WebDriver` instance and programmatically perform each check:

```
List<String> productNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class=\"product-name\"])[" + i + "]"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    productNames.add(element.getText());
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: To answer the question in your comment, if you want the elements, rather than their text, you can store the elements themselves in a list:

```
List<WebElement> productNameElements = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[@class=\"product-name\"])[" + i + "]"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    productNameElements.add(element);
}
```

Now you can access the elements individually by getting them by index from the `productNameElements` list:

```
productNameElements.get(0);   // First item
```

This should be easier to manage than having a separate variable for each item.

Comment: I use the last answer and it works! Thank you very much. But it returns a List of Strings. How can I return separate elements of this List as a variables?

Comment: And what about when I don't know how many elements there will be (sometimes 3 and sometimes 5 for example) and I would like to getText() of them all ?

Comment: Post a new question!

Answer (score 0):

Just addendum to @ELEVATE's answer, You can find element via className:

```
@FindBy(className = "product-name") 
private List<WebElement> tableItems;
```

or

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@class='product-name']")
private List<WebElement> tableItems;
```

but this depends if this is unique identifier...